# Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL 

Tags: symfony-1.4

i changed my onlinesite,in online server,i created new module in schema.yml files.but the above error was comming.i remove catch file content.after that same error was comming.

Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/Planbook/planbook_new" (/)

```
                     #planbook  
                     planbook:
                     url:  /planbook
                     param: { module: planbook, action: index }
                      most_recent:
          url:  /planbook/most_recent
          param: { module: planbook,action: mostrecent }
        planbook_view:
        url: /planbook/planbook_view
        param: { module:planbook,action: view }
        plan_new:
        url:  /planbook/plan_new
        param: { module: planbook,action: new }
        planbook_edit:
        url:  /planbook/planbook_edit
        param: { module: planbook, action: edit }   
        highly_recommended:
        url:  /planbook/highly_recommended
        param: { module: planbook,action: recommended }
       mytrack:
       url:  /mytrack
       param :{ module: planbook,action: mytrack }
       plan_mate:
       url:  /planbook/plan_mate
       param: { module: planbook, action: plan_mate }



      #layer
      layer:
      url:   /layer
     param: { module: layer, action: index }
     layer_new:
     url:   /layer/new
      param: { module: layer, action: new }
     layer_edit:
     url:   /layer/edit
     param: { module: layer, action: edit }
     layer_delete:
     url:   /layer/delete
     param: { module: layer, action: delete }
     layer_view:
    url:   /layer/view
    param: { module: layer, action: view }


             <a href="<?php echo url_for('/Planbook/planbook_new') ?>"
             <a href="<?php echo url_for("@planbook_new") ?>"
```

hi plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you must keep in mind

1. Make sure there are no cache files by using `symfony cc` or you can manually delete the contents of cache folder.
2. Make sure the database connection is configured properly in `databases.yml` as the login page may not require to be connected with database which is not the case regarding other pages.
3. Make sure that the `rewrite_module` has been enabled (I hope you are using wamp which makes it simple to enable it)
4. Make sure that `cache` and `log` folders have write permission (I don't think it will be an issue in a Windows machine)
5. You may also consider going through http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/05-Configuring-Symfony

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Few things to perform:

- check you error log
- use your dev controller (something like frontend_dev.php) to see errors
- and show us the error.

I don't think it's related to htaccess since you can display the login page.

Comment: hi,this is the my frontend_dev.php file code:<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');   and apche error log display the  foloowing error  File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/public_html/web/login, referer: http://localhost/public_html/web/

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();

Comment: Well no, we don't need the frontend_dev code, we knew it. Try to login using `/frontend_dev.php` instead of `/index.php`